# Convert string to decimal with precision in web3 fromWei method

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I have a value `169482670391774` and I know that it should be converted to decimal and has `9` digits after comma, so in this example value after conversion should be `169482.670391774`.

How to convert this value?

What I have so far is:

```
let mapping = web3.utils.unitMap;

let valuePrecision = "";
for (var i = 0; i < accuracy; i++) {
   valuePrecision = valuePrecision + "0";
}
let unitMapValue = 1 + valuePrecision;
let unitMapKey = '';

for (const key in mapping) {
 if (mapping[key] === unitMapValue) {
  unitMapKey = key;
 }
}

let inTxnsInToken = web3.utils.fromWei(web3.utils.toBN(inTxns).toString(), unitMapKey);
let outTxnsInToken = web3.utils.fromWei(web3.utils.toBN(outTxns).toString(), unitMapKey)
```

And this is working but I am feeling that this is not the best method and I can't use:

`web3.utils.toBN(inTxns).toString(), 1000000000)`

Comment: That's pretty much what you have available: Either convert to a string and do the manipulation that way, as you're doing, or do it via math as in `n / 10**9`.

Comment: @Ouroborus but if `web3.utils.unitMap` does not have element for example 2 or 8 digits?